# Spotify can't play the current song

Tags: mac, spotify

[image]

Once in a while my Spotify on Mac laptop will stop working, showing up this blue banner saying "Can't play the current song".

I reinstalled Spotify but it didn't work.

I also found this [thread](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/Can-t-play-the-current-song/td-p/1302172) with multiple suggestions, none of which worked.

So I have to turn to StackExchange geeks. Anyone know some commands or codes to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ugly solution for myself: restart your computer.